# Creating query with Mongoose library (find objects in array)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

This is my Mongoose model of conversation object:

```
const conversationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  participants: [
    {
      id_profile: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }
    }
  ]
});
```

How I can find a conversation object that contains two objects in the array "participants" that have ID = 123456 and ID = 654321? The order of objects in array "participants" can be different.

```
conversation = {
  participants: [
    { id_profile: '123456' },
    { id_profile: '654321' }
  ]
}

conversation = {
  participants: [
    { id_profile: '654321' },
    { id_profile: '123456' }
  ]
}
```

How to create a query using Mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) for this query, which finds docs where a field matches all of a set of values:

```
Conversation.find({'participants.id_profile': {$all: ['123456', '654321']}})
```